# Can I delete some, not all, cells in the UITableViewController edit mode

Tags: ios

I have a table view that I want to delete some of the cells in the edit mode. Is this possible? When I added the edit button to the table view controller and press the edit button, there was a delete icon show up in front of every cell. What I want is only some will have the delete button. Thanks.

Comment: THis link may be help full for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776045/how-to-detect-edit-mode-on-iphone-uitableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Return YES for able to edit. Otherwise NO.