# UITableView editing using notifications?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsnotification, setediting

I have a UITableView with an edit/done button. I would like to make some changes when it enters into edit mode. At the moment, I have overwritten setEditing:animated, but that seems fishy. Is there a notification sent when the tableView enters editing mode, or should I stick to setEditing?

Comment: Similar Question well answered : 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776045/how-to-detect-edit-mode-on-iphone-uitableview

Comment: Well, crap. I missed that one. Sounds like setEditing:animated is still the way to go. Thanks.