# How can I know when UITableView is displaying Insertion/Deletion controls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Case 1. I swipe to delete a row. Table goes in edit mode, but *no* Insertion/Deletion controls are displayed.

[image]

Case 2. I enter edit mode by pressing a button, and the table goes in edit mode, *with* the Insertion/Deletion controls displayed.

[image]

How can I programmatically distinguish between the two cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect edit mode on iphone UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776045/how-to-detect-edit-mode-on-iphone-uitableview)

Comment: I don't think that works for me. My issue is that in both cases the table is in editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

To know if `tableview's` `edit` or `insert` which `operation` is `committed` then it can be known using `UITableView` `delegate` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
       //delete operation
    }
    else if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
       //insert operation
    }
}
```

---

To know if tableview is in editing state then use `UITableView's editing property`

```
if ([tableView isEditing]) 
{
   //TableView in editing mode so do any remaining operation need to be done
}
else
{
   //TableView in not in editing mode
}
```

Comment: Hi Prince! Your answer helps me distinguish between insert and delete, but that is not what I am interested in. I just want to know if the Insertion/Deleted control is displayed or not for a given cell. In both cases the table is in editing mode.